# Linking GUI app against a static lib in QtCreator

Tags: qt, mingw, static-libraries, qt-creator

What is the right way to build a library from source using MinGW and then reference it in the GUI application's project? I'm not familiar with gcc and makefiles, but I think there must be a utility which generates makefiles from existing source.

The library itself doesn't depend on anything except the standard C lib.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the pro file write

```
LIBS += path/to/your/lib
```

This will add the reference to the static library. See the [documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs).